# Magento 2 : What is PCI Compliance And How To Test It?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, pci

Can any one please Explain about PCI Compliance and any method for the testing site.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCI compliance is something any business that accepts credit card payments should consider—regardless of the size or volume of those transactions. PCI compliance is not legally mandated, so you won’t face criminal charges if you aren’t compliant, but if you suffer a data breach while not in full compliance, you could incur steep fines from the PCI Security Standards Council (PCI SSC). Adhering to standards protects both your customers and your business, so it’s worth having.

Bear in mind that Magento CE is regarded as PCI compliant as long as you aren’t storing credit card data, since there are no requirements for the encryption of other information. Thus, for making you Community Edition store compliant, you should eliminate the use of sensitive information within your website by redirecting customers to third party payment platforms.

To get your site PCI compliant, you could use third party payment methods like Paypal, Authorise(dot)net etc where client information's are not stored on your website.

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: Thank you for fast response @Abdul Pathan

Comment: please provide any testing tool link or else help for me